# Firebase - see all read for a specific page

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase (Firestore) project on which, to my surprise, I just reached the free limit of 50k daily reads only while testing simple regular pages of my app.

I tried to find a way to log how much calls are done for each of my app's pages, or by function... I didn't find how to.

Is there a simple way to get this data clarified? I absolutely need to find what calls are causing this before sending anything to production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no breakdown within the Cloud Firestore console or Stack Driver on the source of read operations. If you need something like that, the best I can think of is to log additional information from your clients.

Comment: Like using a custom log in each function making a call to Firebase in order to see her output somehow and detect which one makes too much calls ?

Comment: Yup, either to the console, to a database, or to analytics.

Comment: Thanks. That would be helpful though.

Comment: Yeah, I see this request occasionally, and it would be interesting to be able to look it up. I just think the data volume would probably be prohibitive, but it might be worth to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).